# What am i Doing wrong in to filter search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to development and recently learned react. I am making an event hosting application and implementing a search bar but I'm running into an error when I type something in the search bar.

In the event.jsx file I have handleSearch function.

```
handleSearch = query => {
    this.setState({ searchQuery: query });
  };

getPagedData = () => {
    const {
      searchQuery,
      events: allEvents
    } = this.state;

    let filtered = allEvents;
    if (searchQuery)
      filtered = allEvents.filter(e =>
        e.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
      );
    return { totalCount: filtered.length };
  };
```

this is my search bar component and it is saying that the onChange is not a function.

```
import React from "react";

const SearchBox = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="search-box">
      <input
        className="search-txt"
        type="text"
        name="query"
        placeholder="search"
        value={value}
        onChange={e => onChange(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
      <a className="search-btn" href="">
        <i className="fa fa-search" />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBox;
```

this is what I have in my State-

```
class Events extends Component {
  state = {
    events: getEvents(),
    showDetails: false,
    shownEventID: 0,
    searchQuery: ""
  };


TypeError: onChange is not a function
onChange
src/components/SearchBox.jsx:12`enter code here`
   9 |   name="query"
  10 |   placeholder="search"
  11 |   value={value}
> 12 |   onChange={e => onChange(e.currentTarget.value)}
     | ^  13 | />
  14 | <a className="search-btn" href="">
  15 |   <i className="fa fa-search" />
```

Comment: Can you include the code showing how you render `<SearchBox />`

Comment: <SearchBox /> is all I have in my event.jsx.

Comment: i tried adding         <SearchBox value={this.searchQuery} onChange={this.handleSearch}/> but it gets rid of the error but doesn't function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render the `SearchBox` component with the needed props, using the state value (`this.state.searchQuery`) that you are changing via `onChange` instead of just `this.searchQuery` (which you said you tried in your comment):

```
 <SearchBox value={this.state.searchQuery} onChange={this.handleSearch}/>
```

This will update responsively as `SearchBox` will now re-render every time `searchQuery` changes in the parent state.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `onChange` prop of the input element to a function called `onChange` which might not be defined.

```
onChange={e => onChange(e.currentTarget.value)}
```

The second `onChange` is not a function.